# Weird Chrome Quirk On First Load of Page - fixed, but why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout

I've encountered a weird CSS quirk where the layout misbehaves on the first load of a web page, but it works after you refresh. This behavior is only observed in Chrome.

To reproduce:

1. Open https://coinchat.org/j:offtopic
2. See that the right sidebar is pushed underneath the page, even through there is enough spacing and it is set to `float: right`
3. Refresh the page
4. Observe that the right sidebar is no longer pushed underneath the page.
5. Open a new tab, open https://coinchat.org/j:offtopic
6. Go to 2

The following code fixes this:

```
$("#chatsidebar").hide();
setTimeout(function(){
$("#chatsidebar").show();
}, 1);
```

My question is, **why**?